# Need help to customize a VSCode Theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can anyone tell me the name of the configuration we need to make to change the color of selected lines on VSCode Custom Themes?

I'm using a theme that I really like, called [Omni Owl Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=guilhermerodz.omni-owl). Except for this one small thing: if I select an object, no matter which language or file type, without minimizing its content, I can see everything colored, just like the following image shows:

**Colors when the content is maximized @ Omni Owl Theme**

[image: XX]

But if I minimize its content, its seems like the first line its not selected, as you can see. That line with the arrow on its side should be highlighted as well, just like displayed in the line below. Even though its doesn't seem like that line is selected, it is! Because if I maximize the content, everything is selected and highlighted just like on the first picture!

**Colors when the content is minimized @ Omni Owl Theme**

[image: XX]

What I want to do is edit that property color so that, even when the content is minimized, I can see the color on all selected lines, but I can't find the name! I'm going to put more examples using theme that don't have this "issue", so you can see more clearly what I'm trying to achieve. For this, I'm going to use the default Dark+ Theme and a customized one called [Atom One Dark](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-theme-onedark).

Theme 1:

**Colors when the content is maximized @ Dark+ default VSCode Theme**

[image: XX]

**Colors when the content is minimized @ Dark+ default VSCode Theme**

[image: XX]

Theme 2:

**Colors when the content is maximized @ Atom One Dark**
[image: XX]

**Colors when the content is minimized @ Atom One Dark**

[image: XX]

See how on both themes, even when the object content is minimized, the first line displays the same background color as the one displayed when the object's content is maximized? That's what I'm trying to do on Omni Owl Theme.

I've been searching for the correct configuration name, but I didn't find yet, does anyone know the name?

Comment: out of curiosity, why did you post a new one instead of editing your previous one? deleted questions can count toward [question bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/11107541). And I would likely have deleted my comments there and retracted my close-vote once you made the edit. In any case, thanks for improving your question post.