# Why isn't the remaining visible code of a folded block in VS Code highlighted for me?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm [using](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_color-themes-from-the-marketplace) (/ [I'm writing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme)) a colour theme extension in VS Code / I'm [customizing my theme colours](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme), and when I fold a block of code, I notice that when I select text in the lines that are still visible, the selection has no background highlighting.

Why is that? Are there any workarounds to the problem? And how can I contribute to getting the problem fixed?

Comment: this was created in the stead of a self-deleted question by someone else who gave up on getting an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76292936/11107541

Comment: `why did you post a new one instead of editing your previous one`, where is the previous one

Comment: @rioV8 their previous (and also deleted) one is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76291510/11107541)

Comment: thanks, deleted posts don't show up on the user profile page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the theme / colour customization. Certain theme colours must be given a level of transparency if you want to prevent obscuring other overlapping colourings. In particular, the problematic configuration here is probably with the `editor.foldBackground` colour customization. If you're using a hex colour code (of the form `#RRGGBB` or similar), then you need to add another part to control the transparency / opacity (Ex. `#RRGGBBAA` or similar, where `FF` (hex for 255) means fully opaque, and `00` (hex for 0) means fully transparent).

You can find at least one example of this happening in the wild by googling "`github vscode issues colour theme fold highlight not showing`". It happened with GitHub's GitHub VS Code theme: [Lost text selection when minimizing a block #53](https://github.com/primer/github-vscode-theme/issues/53). Another theme I've seen this happen with is [the "Omni Owl"](https://github.com/guilhermerodz/omni-owl) theme.

---

If you want a workaround with a colour theme extension with this problem, you can customize the colouring for that extension like so:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Theme Name Goes Here]": { // TODO
        "editor.foldBackground": "#RRGGBBAA" // TODO
    }
}
```

To find the value your theme uses, open the downloaded extension's package.json, and either find the theme JSON file manually, or look for the path in the package.json's `contributes` > `themes` property.

---

If you want to contribute to a fix of the root cause of a theme extension problem, raise an issue ticket to the maintainers of the extension describing the problem.

---

Note: As for similar problems to this one, there's a random Gist I found from googling that may be useful in knowing what to make partially transparent: https://gist.github.com/idleberg/004fad51888d745ac609a24d5804050f ([saved on web archive just in case](https://web.archive.org/web/20230520005607/https://gist.github.com/idleberg/004fad51888d745ac609a24d5804050f)).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.